# cordova android plugin - binding services

Tags: android, cordova, android-service, cordova-plugins

I am creating a android cordova app which needs to bind a service. I added the following entry to the manifest.xml

```
<service android:name="com.viatom.azur.BTUtils">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.viatom.azur.BTUtils" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

And try to bond it with the following native code:

```
  private ServiceConnection conn = new ServiceConnection(){
     @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service){
        mBinder = (BTUtils.BTBinder) service;
        System.out.println("Service bound");
     }

     @Override
     public void onServiceDisconnected (ComponentName name){
        System.out.println("Service has been disconnected.");
     }
 };

public String testBindService(){

        Intent intent = new Intent("com.viatom.azur.BTUtils");
        intent.setPackage("com.viatom.azure");
        cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext().bindService(intent, conn, Service.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        return "Hello";


}
```

However eveytime i try to access mBinder at another time in the application, mBinder is null. So i have a few questions:

- At the time the "testBindService" function returns, it triggers the callbackcontext.success. I read that any bound services will be unbound when the context is destroyed. does this mean that if I bind my service in step a, then fire step b from my javascript interface, the mBinder will have already be unbound ?
- Is there a way to keep my native side of the cordova plugin from returning anything untill the service is bound ?

I think the poblem is that the onserviceconnected method is never reached because the execute method of the cordova plugin return before the service is bound. (i read that the bindService method is asynchronous)

any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what does `bindService` return?

Comment: According to the doc: The binding is asynchronous. bindService() returns immediately and does not return the IBinder to the client. To receive the IBinder, the client must create an instance of ServiceConnection and pass it to bindService(). The ServiceConnection includes a callback method that the system calls to deliver the IBinder. In my specific implementation the bindservice should return an instance of my service interface after the on service connected method hits.

Comment: so what does your call of `bindService` return? true or false? if false, try `intent.setPackage("com.viatom.azur");`

Comment: @pskink It returns false, but i already did that :) see the code above in the testBindService method.

Comment: not "com.viatom.azure", but **"com.viatom.azur"**

Comment: still false i'm afraid.

Comment: does your `Service` return non null `Binder` from `onBind` method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126450/discussion-between-mark-stroeven-and-pskink).